# Crud Database update assistance

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I'm doing a CRUD database using PHP and My SQL. I'm having problems with the update page. The data is not updating and I can't seem to figure out the problem.

There are two tables in the database, `user` and `profile`. The user's userid and email are used to establish a connection. The user, once logged in can update their profile(s).

Below is the code I'm using:

```
if (isset($_POST['first_name']) && isset($_POST['last_name']) && isset($_POST['email'])
&& isset($_POST['headline']) && isset($_POST['summary']) && isset($_POST['profile_id'])) 
{

  $sql = "UPDATE profile SET first_name = :first_name,
        last_name = :last_name, email = :email,
        headline = :headline,
        summary = :summary
        WHERE profile_id = :profile_id";

  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute(array(
    ':first_name' => $_POST['first_name'],
    ':last_name' => $_POST['last_name'],
    ':email' => $_POST['email'],
    ':headline' => $_POST['headline'],
    ':summary' => $_POST['summary'],
    ':profile_id' => $_POST['profile_id']));

  $_SESSION['success'] = 'Record updated';
  header( 'Location: index.php' ) ;
  return;
}
```

Comment: if it fails without any errors (assuming you've [got PDO setup to throw exceptions when SQL errors occur](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php) of course), then the most likely explanation is that the WHERE clause didn't match any records in the database. First make sure you've got error handling enabled (this also requires [PHP's overall error handling to be enabled](https://stackify.com/php-error-logs-guide/) too), and make sure it really doesn't error. Then check the value of `$_POST["profile_id"]` and ensure it's correct and there's definitely a matching ID in the database.

Comment: Yes the PDO is setup and I do have error handling.  The profile ID is hidden on the form.  The other fields can be changed. I'm just not figuring it out.  Thanks for your response.

Comment: "The profile ID is hidden on the form"...ok but that's not particularly relevant. what I asked was what the value of the profile ID really is when it reaches the PHP. Have you verified that yet, and checked there is a matching ID in the database? It wasn't really clear from your reply

Comment: maybe I have not done that...On occassions I'm getting the profile_id is missing error.

Comment: "profile_id is missing error" ...where is that error coming from? It's not from the code you've shown, certainly. No, what I meant was to add some debugging like `var_dump($_POST["profile_id"]);` so that you can see if the profile ID being submitted is correct or not.

Comment: No its not coming from what I've shown.  Where do I add this code.  I just starting to learn this language so please bare with me.

Comment: I suggest adding it just before the `if (isset... ` line (i.e. the top line of the code you've shown here)

Comment: P.S. http://www.phpknowhow.com/basics/basic-debugging/ has a simple guide to debugging with PHP, if this is a new topic for you.

Comment: I did and it returned the current profile id.  Thanks again.  Next step in debugging.

Comment: The POST gave an error of undefined index profile/-id. I changed it to GET and it worked.

Comment: seems like your form was sending a GET request rather than POST. The other alternative rather changing the PHP is to change what type of request the form sends. Anyway, glad you fixed it.

Comment: I've just figured out where the problem is.  There's data validation on the form. It must accept an address with a @ sign. It is accepting when it must not.  Now to figure that next problem out.  That's why the record was not updating.  But on my end all checks are in place.